# c# access a nested public class via . operator

Tags: c#, .net, class, nested

I'm looking for a way to access nested public classes using "." operator.
   so for the following example, I want to access Kitchen class nested inside House class.

```
   public class House{

        public class Kitchen{
            //some public properties
            public int numberOfChairs {get; set;}
        }

    }


    //Now want to access Kitchen in another class.
    public class Main{
            House newHouse = new House();
            newHouse.Kitchen.numberOfChairs = 5;
    }


any hint and help is much appreciate.
```

Comment: Nested class is part of type rather than part of instance. What problem are you trying to solve with nested class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Kitchen instance. Something like:

```
House.Kitchen newKitchen = new House.Kitchen();
newKitchen.numberOfChairs = 5;
```

Answer updated based on the reply:

In that case, your House class, also needs to have a Kitchen member.

```
public class House{

    public class Kitchen{
        //some public properties
        public int numberOfChairs {get; set;}
    }

    public House() {
      kitchen = new Kitchen();
    }

    public Kitchen kitchen {get; set;}

}

public class Main{
    House newHouse = new House();
    newHouse.kitchen.numberOfChairs = 5;
}
```

Comment: ok that works, but to be more precise, I want the Kitchen be part of the House. so that I can access kitchen with my "instance" of the House class. is that even possible? thanks for the quick reply

Comment: In that case, your House class, also needs to have a Kitchen member. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx).
That being said, why do you want to nest that class? From the way you want to use it and the fact that you've made it public, why don't you just use a property of type Kitchen?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you only have a nested class declared. Your house holds no instance of that class. Personally, I don't think you even need a nested class. It could be a normal class. But you need an instance:

```
public class House{

    public class Kitchen{
        //some public properties
        public int numberOfChairs {get; set;}
    }

    public Kitchen TheKitchen { get; set; }

}


//Now want to access Kitchen in another class.
public class Main{
        House newHouse = new House();
        newHouse.TheKitchen = new House.Kitchen();   
        newHouse.TheKitchen.numberOfChairs = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property of Kitchen in your House class that way you can access an instance of Kitchen from House.

```
public class House{
    public Kitchen KitchenProp { get; set; }
    public class Kitchen{
            //some public properties
            public int numberOfChairs {get; set;}
        }
    }


    //Now want to access Kitchen in another class.
    public class Main{
            House newHouse = new House();
            newHouse.KitchenProp = new Kitchen();
            newHouse.KitchenProp.numberOfChairs = 5;
    }
```